# Purpose of scss in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ruby on rails. May i know what is the purpose of these js/scss? Everytime I created a new controller, it also create an .scss file.. Is this where should I put my js/css?

I tried to put some image background on my home.scss and try to display it to my div class in my view but it didn't display

Note: I put it in the assets/images/

**Code**

```
.image_bg{
    background-image: image-url('a.jpg')
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="image_bg">

</div>
```

Question: How can I display my image background?

Comment: I don’t know about Rails, but the reason that background didn’t display is probably b/c the element is empty, and thus has a height of 0. Add some content into the `<div>` to give it some height.

Comment: Like this one?  width:50%;
 height:50%;
}

Comment: I put some width and height( width:50%;
 height:50%;
}) like this?

Comment: Why is the question title and the question itself different?

Comment: First I asked what is the purpose of that then second is I tried to make an experiment which is I created an image background but it didnt work

Comment: percent won't work for height unless the height is explicitly set on its parent element -- otherwise, 50% of what? You could use a length unit like px or em. Thought I would only do this to figure out what's going on. Explicitly setting height in CSS is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your model related CSS and JavaScript in those files

You also need to require them in `application.css` and `application.js`

```
/*   
 *= require css_file_name
 */
```

and

```
//= require js_file_name
```

If you don't want rails to create the JavaScript and CSS files along with every new controller or scaffold add this in application.rb

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.assets false      # js files
  g.stylesheets false # scss/sass files
end
```

Comment: `g.helper false` disables the generation of helpers - which although being useful is not directly related to the question. Also the basic scaffolded rails app is setup with `//= require_tree .` so the manifest will automatically include any assets in `app/assets/stylesheets`.

Comment: We mostly remove `//= require_tree` as we have some weird experiences with it

Comment: Yeah but how is that relevant to the OP? His issue is that the code is in the wrong folder. Having both `require css_file_name` and `require_tree .` will cause files to be included twice.

Answer (score 1):

> I am new in ruby on rails. May i know what is the purpose of these
>   js/scss? Everytime I created a new controller, it also create an .scss
>   file. Is this where should I put my js/css?

Rails by default creates a css / js file so you can organize your code by resource.

If you look at `application.css` and `application.js` notice the comment line `*= require_tree .`. This Sprockets directive tells the Rails assets pipeline to include any files in the same directory and its subdirectories when compiling the `application.css/js` file.

The reason your code is not working is that you have placed it in the wrong folder. CSS should be placed in `/app/assets/stylesheets`.
The `/app/assets/images` folder is for actual images used to style the site.

You can disable the generation of assets (if you want to) by using an flag when running the generator:

```
rails g controller foo --skip-assets
```

Or permanently by modifying `config/application.rb`

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.stylesheets false
  g.javascripts false
  # or 
  g.assets false # disables both JS and stylesheets
end
```

---

Added.

If you intend to use SASS you should rename your `application.css` to `application.scss` and remove the sprockets directives:

```
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

And instead use `@import "home"` which tells the SASS compiler to include the file. See https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to include those files into `application.scss`/`application.js` file.
Use:

```
@import "home"
```

Purpose of these files to have well organised codebase. You can organize your assets based on your controller.

Comment: I followed the instruction you gave, and also keithjgrant said to put some width and height (like this? .image_bg{
 background-image: image-url('a.jpg');
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
} )